# Remove #!/ from http local server url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an AngularJs application and everything is working fine.

Yet, I am facing an issue trying to remove #!/ from my url

When I run http-server in console it throws

Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080

Then I enter there and the url automatically changes to http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/

I have this in my route provider

```
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'galleryMap.html',
        controller: 'GalleryMapController'
    })

    .when('/photo/:id', {
        templateUrl: "detail.html",
        controller: 'DetailPageController'
    })
```

The I call the url this way

```
$window.location.href = /photo/3;
$window.location.href = /;
```

Both don't work unless their urls are written like this http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/photo/3
http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/

Is it possible to make it work like a normal url like this
http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo/3
without that horrible tags?

Comment: what router are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White galleryMapApp.config(function ( $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'galleryMap.html',
            controller: 'GalleryMapController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });


});

Answer (score 0):

The "horrible tags" are used to indicate routing on the client-side, rather than the server-side. Loading on the client-side allows the page to not need to completely reload in order to load a new page.

However, you can still perform client-side routing without the hash. You should be able to add this to your application's config to remove the hash:

```
$locationProvider.html5mode(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Im getting blank pague when I try http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo/4

Comment: Are you sure you placed it correctly? Try reading https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag and see if it helps. If not, I'll create an example.